# What User Interface Design or Layout is this

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am currently developing a reservation system application that would require the user to input date and time.
So that would mean that I would have a date picker and a time picker in mu layout file.

Upon doing so, when a user clicks the button to set Date and time of reservation the app will then start an Intent and opens another activity but as far as I see it, It would look awful if I do such so I was wonder how to do this kind of UI so that it would not be as hassle as to start and activity for a result.

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want here. Is it that you've been using a `DatePicker`, but you want a `DatePickerDialog`? Why did you highlight the OK-button? Could you explain the order of events you want, one point at a time?

Comment: Umm i didn't highlight the OK button, it is just an image I found with the UI i kind of desired. So is it a DatePicker Dialog? if so can it apply to Time picker too?

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. Yes, that is a `DatePickerDialog`, and yes, there's also a `TimePickerDialog`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options to implement this behavior.

1. The official [date picker dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) and [time picker dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html).
2. Given that the use of dialogs is discouraged, try using the widgets inline with [CalendarView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) and [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) if you can.
3. A backported version of the widgets [CalendarView](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-calendarview) and [DatePicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker).